# Javascript filter array result

Tags: javascript, arrays, filter

i'm trying to do a javascript filter to an array but somehow im returning one array when it needs to be separated (0 first data 1 second data) so that I can process it easily in a another loop. I hope the below makes sense. Thank you in advance for any help.

JSON INPUT

```
[
    {
        "id": 1,
        "title": "Ford F-150",
        "type": "truck"
    },
    {
        "id": 2,
        "title": "BMW 4 series",
        "type": "car"
    },
    {
        "id": 3,
        "title": "Triumph Scrambler",
        "type": "motorbike"
    },
    {
        "id": 4,
        "title": "Audi A3",
        "type": "car"
    }
]
```

INTO data ARRAY THE FILTERED

```
function filterByProperty(array, prop, value){
    var filtered = [];

    for (var i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
        var obj = array[i];

        for (var key in obj) {

            if (typeof(obj[key] === "object")) {
                var item = obj[key];

                if(obj[prop] == value){
                    filtered.push(item);
                }
            } else {
              console.log("not object");
            }
        }
    }    

    return filtered;
}


var filtereddata = filterByProperty(data, "type", "car");
console.log(filtereddata);
```

When I run this, I only see one array not two?

Comment: I don't understand the question. What is your expected output?

Comment: not sure how to say it but something like this             [
            {
            "id": 2,
            "title": "BMW 4 series",
            "type": "car"
            },
            {
            "id": 4,
            "title": "Audi A3",
            "type": "car"
            }
            ]

Comment: And that is one array. Why would you expect 2 arrays?

Comment: @charlietfl Fairly certain he meant two *objects*

Comment: You'll probably make your life a lot easier if you use the built in `filter` method available on arrays. You don't seem to need 2 different arrays, just one with objects that match a certain criterion, namely the `type` value of specific objects within the array you're filtering.

Comment: @Dev check my answer below using Array.filter()

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [Array.filter](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) to filter by property value

```js
var data = [
      {
        "id": 1,
        "title": "Ford F-150",
        "type": "truck",
        "date": "2017-12-23"
      },
      {
        "id": 2,
        "title": "BMW 4 series",
        "type": "car",
        "date": "2017-12-22"
      },
      {
        "id": 3,
        "title": "Triumph Scrambler",
        "type": "motorbike",
        "date": "2017-12-21"
      },
      {
        "id": 4,
        "title": "Audi A3",
        "type": "car",
        "date": "2017-12-20"
      }
];
        
      function filterByProperty(array, prop, value){
          return newArray = array.filter(function (el) {
            return el[prop] == value;
          });
      }
      function compare(a,b) {
        if (new Date(a.date) < new Date(b.date))
          return -1;
        if (new Date(a.date) > new Date(b.date))
          return 1;
        return 0;
      }

      var filtereddata = filterByProperty(data, "type", "car");
      console.log(filtereddata.sort(compare));
```

Comment: Thank you worked perfectly. What if it had a date - sort by date too [
  {
    "id": 2,
    "date": "20/12/2017"
    "title": "BMW 4 series",
    "type": "car"
  },
  {
    "id": 4,
   "date": "20/11/2017"
    "title": "Audi A3",
    "type": "car"
  }
]

Comment: I didn't get you. Did you mean date in the property value ?

Comment: sorry i meant filter with date

Comment: So your filtering like within your example but with date sort too

Comment: Check my answer. It is now sorted by date after filter.

Comment: Thank you Hari. One last question what if the date format was 04-12-2018 (DD-MM-YYYY)

Answer (score 2):

As an alternative to the other answers, I have changed your code slightly to work. Instead of moving through each key in the each 'vehicle' object it just checks for each vehicles `prop` equaling `value` in the first for loop.

Heres the code:

```js
var data = [
        {
            "id": 1,
            "title": "Ford F-150",
            "type": "truck"
        },
        {
            "id": 2,
            "title": "BMW 4 series",
            "type": "car"
        },
        {
             "id": 3,
             "title": "Triumph Scrambler",
             "type": "motorbike"
        },
        {
            "id": 4,
            "title": "Audi A3",
            "type": "car"
        }
    ];    

    function filterByProperty(array, prop, value){
        var filtered = [];
        for(var i = 0; i < array.length; i++){
            var obj = array[i];
            if(obj[prop] == value)
                filtered.push(obj);
            else{
                console.log("not a " + value);
            }
        }    
        return filtered;
    }


    var filtereddata = filterByProperty(data, "type", "car");

    console.log(filtereddata);
```

hope this helps somebody!

Comment: Put the code in your answer. Use a stack-snippet so it can be seen and run right here, instead of having to go to jsfiddle.

Comment: Roger that Stephen

Answer (score 2):

You're only pushing values to one array and returning one array. That's why you only get one array...

try it like this:

```
function filterProp(data, prop){
    return data.filter(el => {
        return el.type === prop
    })
}
```

Then just use like:

```
console.log(filterProp(data, 'car'))
```

Or if you need to specify the key:

```
function filterProp(data, key, prop){
    return data.filter(el => {
        return el[key] === prop
    })
}

console.log(filterProp(data, 'title', 'BMW'))
```

Comment: This is the _**only**_ answer that actually answers the PO's question "When I run this, I only see one array not two?"

Answer (score 2):

In ES6, arrays have builtin method `.filter` to filter items.
Its sugar syntax for `Array.prototype.filter()`

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter

```
const data = [
    {
        "id": 1,
        "title": "Ford F-150",
        "type": "truck"
    },
    {
        "id": 2,
        "title": "BMW 4 series",
        "type": "car"
    },
    {
        "id": 3,
        "title": "Triumph Scrambler",
        "type": "motorbike"
    },
    {
        "id": 4,
        "title": "Audi A3",
        "type": "car"
    }
];

const filter = (d, prop, value) => d.filter((obj) => obj[prop] === value);
const filtereddata = filter(data, "type", "car");

console.log(filtereddata);
```

Answer (score 2):

First a note about `typeof` which is a keyword, not a function.

Using it like a function means it evaluates `obj[key] == "object"` first.
Since that evaluates to `false`, `typeof` then returns `boolean` because `typeof false` is `boolean`.

`boolean` is a [truthy](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Truthy) value, so you never hit your `else` clause.

That said, you can fix your function by:

- eliminating the `typeof` check.
- adding another check to make sure the `key` matches the passed in `prop`.
- and pushing the `obj` into the array to return.

```js
function filterByProperty(array, prop, value) {
    var filtered = [];
    for (var i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
        var obj = array[i];
        for (var key in obj) {
            if (key === prop && obj[prop] == value) {
                filtered.push(obj);
            }
        }

    }

    return filtered;

}


const data = [{
        "id": 1,
        "title": "Ford F-150",
        "type": "truck"
    },
    {
        "id": 2,
        "title": "BMW 4 series",
        "type": "car"
    },
    {
        "id": 3,
        "title": "Triumph Scrambler",
        "type": "motorbike"
    },
    {
        "id": 4,
        "title": "Audi A3",
        "type": "car"
    }
];

var filtereddata = filterByProperty(data, "type", "car");

console.log(filtereddata);
```

Alternatively, you could use [`Array.filter`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) instead:

```js
const filterByProperty = (arr, prop, value) => arr.filter(o => o[prop] && o[prop] === value);

const data = [{
        "id": 1,
        "title": "Ford F-150",
        "type": "truck"
    },
    {
        "id": 2,
        "title": "BMW 4 series",
        "type": "car"
    },
    {
        "id": 3,
        "title": "Triumph Scrambler",
        "type": "motorbike"
    },
    {
        "id": 4,
        "title": "Audi A3",
        "type": "car"
    }
];

const filtered = filterByProperty(data, 'type', 'car');
console.log(filtered);
```

Answer (score 1):

Try using Array.filter(callback)

```
function filterByProperty(array, prop, value) {
    var filtered = array.filter(item => {
      item[prop] === value;
    }
    return filtered;
}

var filtereddata = filterByProperty(data, "type", "car");

console.log(filtereddata);
```

Answer (score 1):

you can use this function:

```js
var data =[
        {
        "id": 1,
        "title": "Ford F-150",
        "type": "truck"
        },
        {
        "id": 2,
        "title": "BMW 4 series",
        "type": "car"
        },
        {
        "id": 3,
        "title": "Triumph Scrambler",
        "type": "motorbike"
        },
        {
        "id": 4,
        "title": "Audi A3",
        "type": "car"
        }
        ]
        
        filterByProperty(data, 'type', 'car');
        function filterByProperty(data, prop, value){
         for(i=0; i<data.length; i++){
           if(data[i][prop]==value){
             console.log(data[i]);
            }
          }
        }
```

Answer (score 1):

As manavM said the internal array.filter class is made for this.
The original array remains untouched. 
The second array filteredArr contains all of the items that returned a true to your return statement.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter

https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_filter.asp

```js
function filterByProperty(arr, prop, val) {
    const filteredArr = arr.filter(function (v) {
      return typeof v === 'object' && v[prop] == val;
    });
    console.log(arr);
    console.log(filteredArr);
};
filterByProperty([{
    "id": 1,
    "title": "Ford F-150",
    "type": "truck"
    },{
    "id": 2,
    "title": "BMW 4 series",
    "type": "car"
    },{
    "id": 3,
    "title": "Triumph Scrambler",
    "type": "motorbike"
    },{
    "id": 4,
    "title": "Audi A3",
    "type": "car"
    }], "type", "car");
```